# How do you use unzip_file()?

Tags: wp-filesystem, ziparchive

I have been trying to use the [`unzip_file()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unzip_file) function. It says `undefined` so I looked into it and the [`WP_Filesystem()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) must be called and set up. So easy, right?

```
require_once(ABSPATH .'/wp-admin/includes/file.php');

WP_Filesystem();

unzip_file( $zip, $dest  );
```

Even this shows as `undefined`, and I don't see any documentation on it. I am trying to use the unzip feature to unpack a separate plugin during theme install.

Comment: You need to debug. Use breakpoints or turn WP_DEBUG on. If the returned var from `unzip_file()` is undefined, then the function stop working.

Comment: Apparently you can't use this outside of admin? This is not heavily documented so I'm quite in the dark.

Comment: Huh? What about the admin? `WP_DEBUG` works in frontend and backend. And `unzip_file()` also. Please post your code.

Comment: Code is now above in my post. At first I called "unzip_file" which did nothing. Then I did WP_Filesystem();...which you know was undefined as well. The script was initiated after a  theme activation hook - so for some reason these functions are invisible in that context.

Comment: You need to use `$creds` from `request_filesystem_credentials` to #Initializing_WP_Filesystem_Base https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API#Initializing_WP_Filesystem_Base

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once(ABSPATH .'/wp-admin/includes/file.php');

global $wp_filesystem;
if ( ! $filesystem ) {
  WP_Filesystem();
    if ( ! $wp_filesystem )
      nuke_the_world_because_wpfs_cannot_be_initialized_in_case_of_missing_arguments('!');
}

$result = unzip_file( $zip, $dest );
if ( is_wp_error( $result ) )
   nuke_the_world();
```

Maybe some error handling make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get WordPress to unzip the file, PHP has its own zip file implementation (documentation can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). Simple examples can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php.